# Using another Provider inside class which extends ChangeNotifier in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

**Scenario:** I've a `class` `FirebaseManger` which handles calls to `Firebase` and extends `ChangeNotifier` to let other classes access it using `Provider`. Now I've one more `class` `UserManager` which extends `ChangeNotifier` as well and contains a list(`List<User>`) of all users in the `Firestore`.

**Question:** Inside an `async` method in `FirebaseManager` I want to access `UserManager` using provider and fill the `List<User>`. So, is it a good practice to use another provider inside one. If it's not then what can be a better design for this scenario?

**PS:** I'm somehow able to pass the `context` for `UserManager` provider inside `FirebaseManager`.